# how to convert an integer value to a specific ascii character in c++

Tags: c++, ascii, int

I'm new to C++ and I'm trying to do something that should be pretty basic.

I have a small loop in C++ that just displays a sequence of numbers and I would like to convert these numbers into specific ASCII characters. Something like this:

```
    for (int k = 0; k < 16; k++) {
        display(65+k);
    }
```

And the result should look like this:

ABCDEFGH... etc

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

EDIT based on clarification:
Judging from the error message `display` takes a C-style string. You can build one like this:

```
for (int k = 0; k < 16; k++) {
    char str[2] = { 65 + k };  // Implicitly add the terminating null.
    display(str);
}
```

Comment: This is an incorrect solution. The OP wanted to output *ASCII* characters, but the value of 'A' depends on the host encoding. If you compile this on a AS/400 then it would send 0xc2 0xc3 0xc4 .. to the output stream.

Comment: @Luther The OP specifically requested that the result be characters. I don't understand how `std::cout` on such a system wouldn't translate `'A'+1` for example into `'B'` on the display, regardless of what numeric representation the host actually uses.

Comment: cout does not know how to make an 'A' on your display. It only knows how to send character codes to your display (or a file) and its up to your display to interpret the codes and show an 'A' for a specific code. If the program and the display disagree on the code for 'A' you have a problem.

Comment: The OP made the requirement that the program should produce characters in the ASCII encoding, which means that a 65 should be produced for an 'A' and so on. But if the program is compiled under a system where an 'A' in the source means a differnet code (EBCDIC), then we have the disagree situation. Therefore, we can not use 'A' to produce ASCII, but have to use the character code directly.

Comment: Actually the OP has impossibly conflicting requirements as I read it now: First that it produce ASCII and second that it produce characters such as "ABCDEFGH". My approach (I believe) solves that latter question, and I agree it won't always produce ASCII output.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't clarify the question. The display() method above requires that a string be passed to it. So really what I need is to go from an integer say 65 to a string (in this case the letter A). With the code suggested I get the error "Invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*'.
Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

That would be

```
#include <iostream>  
int main() {  
for (int k = 0; k < 16; k++) {
        std::cout.put(65+k);
    }
}
```

for C++

Comment: an improvement would be to replace 65 with 'A'

Comment: Not really. Actually we have not guarantee that the codes following 'A' are letters at all. If this ran on a AS/400 the program would produce a file of gibberish for anyone reading it as ASCII. 65 is *correcter* than 'A', but 'A' is nicer to the loose^H^H^H^H^H people who haven't memorized the ASCII table.

Comment: Luther is correct that this solution will portably produce ASCII characters in any environment with at least 7-bit wide streams (while C `char` type must be at least 8 bits, that doesn't prevent a narrowing conversion when writing to disk or stdout), regardless of whether the environment uses ASCII as its native format.